# Foreign key in Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, foreign-keys

Hey I need help with the following set-up, I cant seem to find a solution:

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :education
end
```

**Education.rb**

```
class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

-The Users table holds 'id'(id of the user) and 'education_id' and other columns which are of no importance now.

-The Educations table holds 'id' and 'name' which is the name of the education.

I'd like to get the *Education name* by using the *education_id* in the Users table to link to *id in Educations*.

I want to be able to use that in the view by using some syntax like

```
<%= user.education %>
```

I believe its a real simple solution but I cant seem to find it

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Ref [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association)

As per your Model declaration you should have `user_id` column in your educations table.

OR you have to change your model declaration to following

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :education
end


class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user
end
```

Comment: hmm thats unlogical isnt it, there is an ID in Educations which you should be able to link to education_id in Users

Comment: then just change your Model declaration to make it work for you

Comment: thanks that just worked lol, it doesnt make direct sense to me but it will in the long run i hope :)

Comment: You're not the only one who thinks that is the wrong way around, but you do get used to it.  Think to your self, if the model has an "x_id" in the database, then the model should "belong to x"

Answer (score 0):

by seeing the comment i think you need proper explanation
first of all  do

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :education
   end
   class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_one :user
   end
```

the table which has the foreign key in this case education_id should have belongs_to( in this case ) user and the table of which the foreign key is created here education_id has has_one